# Resetting value when modulus computes to 0

Tags: conditionals, numbers

Am doing the following computation where `dmax` is `8`, whilst `dcur` start at `1` and increases bf increments of `1`.  I would like that when `(mod dcur dmax)` is `0`, I use the value `8` rather than the value `0`.

```
(let (n (mod dcur dmax))
  (message " dcur: %d | n: %d" dcur n))
```

I get the following when running the program

```
 dcur: 1 | n: 1
 dcur: 2 | n: 2
 dcur: 3 | n: 3
 dcur: 4 | n: 4
 dcur: 5 | n: 5
 dcur: 6 | n: 6
 dcur: 7 | n: 7
 dcur: 8 | n: 0
 dcur: 9 | n: 1
 dcur: 10 | n: 2
 dcur: 11 | n: 3
 dcur: 12 | n: 4
 dcur: 13 | n: 5
 dcur: 14 | n: 6
 dcur: 15 | n: 7
 dcur: 16 | n: 0
 dcur: 17 | n: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(let (n (mod dcur dmax))
  (when (zerop n) (setq n 8))
  (message " dcur: %d | n: %d" dcur n))
```